# ASP.Net GridView.SelectRow(rowIndex as integer) method fails to pass rowIndex to SelectedIndexChanged event handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

In some ASP.Net code-behind, I call the `SelectRow` method of a custom grid control that inherits from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView`.

Making the call:

```vb
If (ProgressGrid.Rows.Count > 0) Then
    ProgressGrid.SelectRow(0)
End If
```

As expected, this generates a `SelectedIndexChanged` event, which is picked up by the handler:

```vb
Protected Sub ProgressGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ProgressGrid.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using db As New DataContext
        Dim course = (From c In db.CourseResults
         Where c.MemberID = MemberID AndAlso c.ResultID = CInt(ProgressGrid.SelectedDataKey.Value)
         Select c).Single

        ' more code here

    End Using
End Sub
```

My problem is that `ProgressGrid.SelectedDataKey` is `nothing` inside my event handler, causing a null-reference error.  While debugging with Visual Studio 2010, I can see from the call stack that the `ProgressGrid.SelectRow(0)` was hit and that the `ProgressGrid.Rows.Count` is greater than zero.  So why are all the "Selected..." properties on the `ProgressGrid` object set to `nothing` or `-1`?  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The custom Grid class contains this property which overrides the default `GridView` behavior:

```vb
    Public Overrides Property SelectedIndex() As Integer
        Get
            If AutoPostback Or AllowSelect = False Then
                Return MyBase.SelectedIndex
            Else
                If HttpContext.Current Is Nothing Then
                    Return Nothing
                    Exit Property 'Exit if in design mode
                End If
                Dim index As String = Page.Request(Me.ClientID + "_SelectedRow")
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(index)) Then
                    If (ViewState("SelectedIndex") Is Nothing) Then
                        Return -1
                    Else
                        Return ViewState("SelectedIndex")
                    End If
                Else
                    ViewState.Add("SelectedIndex", index)
                    Return CType(index, Integer)
                End If
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            MyBase.SelectedIndex = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

The debugger is unable to display the details for `MyBase` and the first calls to `MyBase.SelectedIndex = value` have the debugger's quick watch window return a null reference error.  Once I reach the event handler, break points in the above property indicate that `MyBase.SelectedIndex` is `nothing`, despite attempting to set it to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that setting the `ViewState` in the custom grid's `SelectedIndex` property fixed my problem.  This allowed `ViewState` to hold the new index value and return it when the `Get` method was called on the property.

```vb
Set(ByVal value As Integer)
    MyBase.SelectedIndex = value
    ViewState("SelectedIndex") = value
End Set
```

Comment: Awesome, always nice to answer your own questions, isn't it? :-)

Comment: It is.  Asking the question helped clarify my thinking and lead me to investigate something I would not otherwise have considered.  In this case, I did not pay attention to the Grid being a custom control and certainly didn't catch the custom `SelectedIndex` property until I realized anyone helping me would ask for it.  :)